# Converting Feet-Inches to Inches Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I have a large excel spreadsheet which contains heights of different athletes in the form of

> 6' 4.25"
>     6' 2.75"

I am stuck on trying to find a single formula that can convert all of these heights to strictly inches.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because these are string text and not actual numbers we need to parse the data.  The following will grab the parts of the string and convert to the number:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("'",A1)-1)*12 + MID(A1,FIND("'",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("'",A1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing something wrong but when I enter that formula in Excel is returning a #value error

Comment: @Nate: Works perfectly for me here.

Comment: @Nate Then your data is not as you stated in your original post.  Please post a picture of the actual data.

Comment: @Nate check to ensure you do not have spaces and/or other unprintable characters in your data.

Comment: I tried to delete the space between the feet and inches and I still received the #value error

Comment: @Nate check the area after and before not the space between.  There may be spaces after or before which would cause the error.  I tried your values and they all work for me.

Comment: I think I figured out what it may be. Instead of using the double quotes for the inches two single quotes were used. How would that change the formula?

Comment: Change the last `-1` to `-2` @Nate

Comment: @Nate please mark the answer you end up using as correct by clicking the check mark by that answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a formula that handles feet and inches (5'10"), just feet (5'), just inches (60"), and a number representing inches (60). It's based on brettdj's version.

`=IFERROR(IFERROR(CONVERT(LEFT(A1,FIND("'",A1)-1),"ft","in"),0)+IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-IFERROR(FIND("'",A1),0)),"""","")+0,0),A1)`

Comment: Thanks @michael, this helped me out a lot - very complete answer. Whilst the answer marked as solution is correct this is more thorough.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to get `CONVERT` in there as it is an under-utilised function. Something like

```
=CONVERT(LEFT(A1,FIND("'",A1)-1),"ft","in")+SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("'",A1)),"""","")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have the input in feet in one cell (say E4) and the input in inches in another cell (say F4, next to it). You can get your result by having a third cell (G4) with this formula:

```
= SUM(E4 * 12) + F4
```